# C++ strncpy parameters "optimized out"; overwrites random memory

Tags: c++, linux, fuse

First of all, I want to apologize for not being able to narrow down the problem enough to be able to share a short program that reproduces the bug.

An external library (FUSE) call to `strncpy` "randomly" overwrites a `shared_ptr<mutex>` in my code, which causes a segfault when I try to lock that mutex. I ran my program with valgrind and it didn't catch any memory errors (valgrind flags below). When I run my code in gdb and set a watchpoint on that `shared_ptr`, it breaks on the call to strncpy. gdb says that all of `strncpy`'s parameters (dest, src, and nbytes) have been "optimized out", which makes me think it's using uninitialized memory for that call. Am I interpreting this correctly? Any idea what the cause could be?

Here's the stack trace from gdb when the pointer is overwritten:

```
#0  __strncpy_ssse3 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-ssse3.S:2482
#1  0x0000003245809094 in strncpy (__len=<optimized out>, __src=<optimized out>, __dest=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/bits/string3.h:120
#2  add_name (buf=<optimized out>, bufsize=<optimized out>, s=<optimized out>, name=<optimized out>) at fuse.c:907
#3  0x000000324580997c in try_get_path (f=<optimized out>, nodeid=<optimized out>, name=<optimized out>, path=<optimized out>, wnodep=<optimized out>, need_lock=<optimized out>) at fuse.c:956
#4  0x000000324580a281 in get_path_common (f=<optimized out>, nodeid=<optimized out>, name=<optimized out>, path=<optimized out>, wnode=<optimized out>) at fuse.c:1152
#5  0x0000003245812432 in fuse_lib_unlink (req=<optimized out>, parent=<optimized out>, name=<optimized out>) at fuse.c:1198
#6  0x0000003245817057 in fuse_ll_process_buf (data=0x6f5650, buf=0x7fffffffd850, ch=<optimized out>) at fuse_lowlevel.c:2441
#7  0x000000324581388f in fuse_session_loop (se=0x6f8410) at fuse_loop.c:40
#8  0x000000324580b698 in fuse_loop (f=<optimized out>) at fuse.c:4309
#9  0x000000324581bb8f in fuse_main_common (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>, op=<optimized out>, op_size=<optimized out>, user_data=<optimized out>, compat=<optimized out>) at helper.c:355
#10 0x000000000046f1b6 in main (argc=4, argv=0x7fffffffdec8) at ../src/fuse.cpp:100
```

Here's the arguments I ran valgrind with:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes --num-callers=20 --track-fds=yes
```

Comment: Try compiling without optimizations.

Comment: What version of FUSE?

Comment: @Drew: FUSE version 2.6, I think it's the latest

Comment: @AShelly: Optimizations are already off (-O0 flag)

Comment: @user1091954 FUSE 2.6 is from 2006.  My web searches show several similar crashes in older versions than the newest, which is 2.9.2.  Let me know if upgrading helps and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Maybe I've been using 2.9.2 all along. I've been using whatever version the Fedora Core 18 repos provide. I changed the FUSE_USE_VERSION define from 26 to 29, but I still get the bug.

Comment: To clarify, I did verify that I'm currently using 2.9.2.

Comment: [strncpy?](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html)

Comment: @KeithThompson It's being called from the FUSE library, nothing I can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug was the result of creating a `shared_ptr` with `new`, then typecasting it to a `weak_ptr` and deleting it.

Comment: Type-casting a shared pointer?  And the compiler let you do that?  Ewww.

Comment: I'm using a C library and it only provides a uint64_t to store a handle. I pass the library a struct containing a pointer to a weak pointer cast as a uint64_t. The library calls my functions and passes them the struct containing the pointer to a weak pointer. I accidentally set the pointer (cast as a uint64_t) to the address of a shared pointer instead of a weak pointer.

Answer (score 1):

> gdb says that all of `strncpy`'s parameters (dest, src, and nbytes) have been "optimized out", which makes me think it's using uninitialized memory for that call. Am I interpreting this correctly?

No. This just means that the optimizer has removed some of the function prologue boilerplate that would allow the debugger to reliably print the arguments to the function.  This is very common with simple functions at any reasonable level of optimization.

Here's a simple example:

```
int
mystrcpy(char *p, const char *q)
{
    while (*p++ = *q++);
}
```

compiled with `-g -O0` you see it spill its arguments to the stack immediately:

```
mystrcpy:
.LFB0:
        .file 1 "t.c"
        .loc 1 5 0
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)      <<< here
        movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)     <<< and here
        ...
```

Then the compiler generated debug info about that:

```
    .section        .debug_info
    ...
    .uleb128 0x7
    .string "p"   <<< from char *p
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x4
    .long   0x65
    .byte   0x2
    .byte   0x91
    .sleb128 -24  <<< not 100% sure but this is probably related to frame offset
    .uleb128 0x7
    .string "q"
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x4
    .long   0x72
    .byte   0x2
    .byte   0x91
    .sleb128 -32   <<< note adjacent to p
```

When you crank up `-O2 -g`, despite `-g` the function becomes much smaller:

```
mystrcpy:
.LFB11:
        .file 1 "t.c"
        .loc 1 5 0
        .cfi_startproc
        (at this point we start copying, using the input regs directly)
```

And now there's no reference to `p` or `q` in the debug information.  As you can see from this example you can probably find the information you want in registers, but you will have to disassemble and understand the function to interpret them.  And if your function has called *other* functions you may have to find where your registers got spilled to the stack (could be quite far away for callee-saves regs).